# What is Chrome extension LsiHelper?

Tags: browser-addons

I am running Windows 8 without admin rights. I have installed Chrome on it (with no admin rights) and once synced with Google account it brought my usual extensions EditThisCookie, ABP, Google Docs, Google docs offline, Postman and Postman REST client.

Today I noticed this LsiHelper extension has got added to Chrome.

It shows as this.

[image] 
[image]

There is no option to remove or disable this extension.

---

- **How was this extension installed**?
- How to remove it without having admin rights?(and make sure it doesn't come back).
- Is this unsafe?

Comment: is this a work computer?

Comment: @schroeder Yes, this is work computer. One other coworker has same extension on his chrome but there are few others who don't.

Comment: you might need to ask your tech support on this one - your screenshots say they installed it

Comment: Did you ever find out what installed this?

Comment: @afreeland Not really. Admin didn't install this though. A day or two after I posted the question, there was a Google Chrome software updates and LsiHelper went away after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google's own Product Forums, [What is LsiHelper 1.1?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/3HfVV6EOJFc/qT54iFg1ON4J), it is malware:

> I noticed the reference to "Enterprise Policy". This is malware. See [Here](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/installed-enterprise-policy-removal/)

That link then describes malware using the “Installed by enterprise policy” extension:

> The “Installed by enterprise policy” extension are usually adware
>   programs that displays pop-up ads, advertisement banners and sponsored
>   links within Google Chrome. Unfortunately, some free downloads do not
>   adequately disclose that other software will also be installed and you
>   may find that you have installed the malicious “Installed by
>   enterprise policy” extension without your knowledge.

It is then followed by these removal tips:

> To remove “Installed by enterprise policy” extension from Google
>   Chrome, follow any of these options:
>
> - OPTION 1: [Remove the “Installed by enterprise policy” extension Google Chrome](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/installed-enterprise-policy-removal/#removal)
> - OPTION 2: [Manually remove the “Installed by enterprise policy” extension from your registry and computer](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/installed-enterprise-policy-removal/#manual)
> - OPTION 3: [Restore Windows to an earlier time to remove the “Installed by enterprise policy” from Windows](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/installed-enterprise-policy-removal/#restore)

Comment: Just because an extension is installed via "Enterprice Policy" does *not* mean that it is malware.